Running V2rayN on Arch
I've tried different alternatives such as Qv2ray and V2rayA and they just lack basic  functions such as real delay and httpupgrade support and other stuff
Is there any way to run v2rayN on arch and set it up so its locathost proxy sets up on my proxy settings?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
